# Output contacts from csv file with PHP

Tags: php

I need to be able to output contacts via a loop on a page from a CSV file downloaded from Outlook.

If the user has the file on their local machine, I suppose I need some sort of upload mechanism, then let my script read uploaded file and then run the results via some loop and output one contact per line.

Each line will have a checkbox next to a contact and if checked, the form will post results and they will be written into db.

Normal format of Outlook .CSV [example file here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12119)

I only need Name and email. First and last can be merged in just Name. I suppose i need to run some sort of email validation to reject malformed entries...

Just trying to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php), which can read your CSV file and return an array to you. This is really easy to work with.

Comment: This is cool. But they all assume the file is on the server. What if it's on user's machine...

Comment: @santa Then you'll have to let the user upload it to the server before you can do anything with php. php is server-side, you can't work around that.

Answer (score 1):

For information about reading the `csv` file check out this http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php